# Visualforce page behaviour in mobile device

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, outputlink

I have a visualforce page which I have embedded in a section of a page layout. This visualforce page has a link to a record detail page. I am using this page layout in mobile device too. In web interface when I click the link to the record , the record's detail page opens up, but when I use mobile device and select the link, it open in another page separately and from there I have to click again to open the detail page.

Is this weird behaviour in mobile? Is there a way to make it one click open in mobile device too?

VF page:

```
<script> 
function navSObject(reciord) 
{ 
    sforce.one.navigateToSObject(reciord,"detail"); 
};
</script>
<table class="pageBlockCss" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"  border="1">
<tr class="headerRow" >
<th style="width: 25%;" bgcolor="grey"><font size="1">Name</font></th>
<th style="width: 25%;" bgcolor="grey"><font size="1">Number</font></th>
<th style="width: 25%;" bgcolor="grey"><font size="1">Phone</font></th>
<th style="width: 25%;" bgcolor="grey"><font size="1">Email</font></th>
</tr>
<apex:repeat value="{!AccList}" var="account">
<tr class="dataRow even first">
<td><font size="1"><apex:outputLink value="/{!account.id}" target="_blank" onclick="navSObject('{!Account.Id}')">{!account.name}</apex:outputLink></font></td>
<td><font size="2"><apex:outputText value="{!account.Location_Number__c}"/></font></td>
<td><font size="2"><apex:outputText value="{!account.phone}"/></font></td>
<td><font size="2"><apex:outputText value="{!account.Email__c}"/></font></td>
</tr>
</apex:repeat>
</table>
```

Screen shot of how it looks on the page:

[image]

When I click est in mobile device it open a new page with only the table there and I have to click the est again to go to detail page.

Comment: Just a note, it is best practice to use `{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, account.Id)}` for the link. Also, where is `navSObject` defined?

Comment: I don't have navSObject defined anywhere. Is that the reason of two clicks to open a link of VF page in mobile?

Comment: Could be...also you shouldn't be using `target="_blank"` in this instance...

Comment: Any suggestions ? I will remove target again and see if it makes any difference , but I think it's shows the sane behavior

Comment: Pls see my edited questions with navSobject defined as a script. I removed target but it still the same behavior. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let's [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41221/salesforce1-redirect) about it.